# Matching keys from one array to another and creating a new array with their values?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop, match

Hi I have two arrays the first one looks like this:

```
array(  
    00000 => array(  
                 0 => 123,
                 1 => 456,
                 2 => 789,  
               )
    11111 => array(  
                 0 => 987,  
                 1 => 654,  
                 2 => 321,  
               )
```

My second array looks like this:

```
array(  
    00000 => 'apples',  
    11111 => 'bananas',
)
```

What am trying to do is match the keys from the 1st array with the keys in array 2nd then if they match take the values of key pair value array of the first array and make them keys for a brand new array and the values of the second array make them values for the brand new array. Something like this:

```
array(  
    123 => 'apples',  
    456 => 'apples',  
    789 => 'apples',  
    987 => 'bananas',  
    654 => 'bananas',  
    321 => 'bananas',  
)
```

Any help thanks!

Comment: Your second array cannot exist... you can't have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: Yes sorry edited it i added too many as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi actually i did some research on php.net found a solution:

```
$array3 = array_keys($array1);  
$array4 = array_keys($array2);
$array5 = array_intersect($array3, $array4)
$array6 = array();  

foreach($array5 as $id) {  
    foreach($array1[$id] as $userId) {  
        $array6[$userId] = $array2[$id]  
    }  
}
```

Probably made more arrays than needed but this works and matches keys of both arrays before assigning values to new array.

Thanks to all that answered and helped!

Answer (score 1):

so im assuming u have 2 arrays (and you fixed second array to have unique keys)

```
$array3 = array (); //for the result
foreach ($array1 as $seg)
{

   foreach ($seg as $key)
   {
      $array3[$key] = $array2[$seg];
   }     
}
```

Comment: Yes i fixed it i accidentally typed too many there. Thanks but this wont match up the 1st and 2nd arrays keys as the condition before putting in the new value into the array. this will display all as apples. =/

Comment: you must have a different problem, because this code works just fine. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array = array(
    "00000" => array(
                 0 => 123,
                 1 => 456,
                 2 => 789,
    ),
    "11111" => array(
                 0 => 987,  
                 1 => 654,  
                 2 => 321,  
    )
);

$arr = array(  
    "00000" => 'apples',  
    "11111" => 'bananas',
);

$array3 = array();
foreach ($array as $keyas => $segs)
{
    foreach ($segs as $key)
   {
       $array3[$key] = $arr[$keyas];
   }     
}
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($array3);
 unset($array3);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [123] => apples
    [456] => apples
    [789] => apples
    [987] => bananas
    [654] => bananas
    [321] => bananas
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but this like the answer above also returns all values as apples it never matches the keys of both arrays as condition.

Comment: What is your requirement @lawrence

Comment: Hi actually I found a solution but cant answer my own question yet because I don't have enough rep. I used array_keys to find the keys of both arrays and intersect to match them in a new array then using that assign the values. I'll post answer later! Thanks for helping anyway!